# How to change URL parameter to slashes?

Tags: php

I want to change the url of my website from:

http://localhost/bimbsec/v3/index.php?p=page-name

to

http://localhost/bimbsec/v3/page-name

Can i just use pure PHP function? Or there is any best way?

Comment: If you are running an `Apache` server, you can accomplish this using `.htaccess`. You can learn more about `.htaccess` here: http://www.htaccess-guide.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save this file as .htaccess on your project dir and then run like

http://localhost/test/test-page

You will get test-page like in $_GET var

Array ( [p] => test-page )

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

  Options +FollowSymLinks
  RewriteEngine On

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

  RewriteRule (.*) index.php?p=$1& 
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Works like champs! Thank you.